# Making all functions false

Tags: actionscript-3, function, boolean

I am trying to add a menu to my game. But for that i need to make the code below false. do i need to make every function false or can i use an extra main function to do this? If there is an alternative i would be happy to hear it. Thanks if u leave a comment. :)

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    public class Docter extends MovieClip
    {
        private var nieuwX:Number = 0;
        private var nieuwY:Number = 0;

        private var snelheid:Number;

        private var snelheidX:Number;
        private var snelheidY:Number;

        private var totaleAfstand:Number;
        private var vorigeAfstand:Number;
        private var momenteleAfstand:Number;

        public var heeftSieraad:Boolean = false;

        private var deltaTime = 0;
        private var currentTime = 0;

        public var startGame:Boolean;

        public function startGame{


            public function Docter() 
            {

                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Setup);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, docEenClick);
            }
            public function AddSieraad():void
            {
                AddGlow();
                heeftSieraad = true;
            }
            private function AddGlow():void
            {
                var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0xFFFF00,1);
                this.filters = [glow];
            }
            public function RemoveSieraad():void
            {
                heeftSieraad = false;
                this.filters = [];
            }
            private function docEenClick(evt:MouseEvent)
            {

                dispatchEvent(new Event(Main.ADD_SCORE_EVENT));

            }

            private function positie(){

                this.nieuwX = this.randomXPositie();
                this.nieuwY = this.randomYPositie();

                this.totaleAfstand = this.krijgAfstand();

                var tijd:Number = this.totaleAfstand / this.snelheid;

                snelheidX = (nieuwX - this.x)/tijd;
                snelheidY = (nieuwY - this.y)/tijd;
            }

            private function Setup(evt:Event){
                this.x = this.randomXPositie();
                this.y = this.randomYPositie();

                snelheid = 70;

                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, verplaatsDocEen);
            }

            private function randomXPositie():Number{

                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+ (stage.stageWidth + this.width) + this.width) - this.width);
            }

            private function randomYPositie():Number{

                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+ (stage.stageHeight + this.height) + this.height) - this.height);
            }

            private function krijgAfstand():Number{

                return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - this.nieuwX,2) + Math.pow(this.y - this.nieuwY,2));
            }

            private function verplaatsDocEen(evt:Event)
            {
                deltaTime = getTimer()/1000 - currentTime;
                currentTime = getTimer()/1000;

                this.vorigeAfstand = this.momenteleAfstand;
                this.momenteleAfstand =this.krijgAfstand();

                if (this.momenteleAfstand < this.vorigeAfstand)
                {

                    this.x += this.snelheidX * deltaTime;
                    this.y += this.snelheidY * deltaTime;
                }

                else
                {
                    this.positie();
                }
            }
            public function dispose()
            {
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, verplaatsDocEen);
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Setup);
                this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, docEenClick);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "make the code false"? I don't understand.

Comment: Well i want to make a menu in the beginning. My problem is now that the game already begins. For Example i want to make a play button. If u press the play button the game will begin.

Comment: Is "Docter" your Document Class?

Comment: @bwroga its not my main class if that is what you mean.

Comment: In your main class, you could create a button and listen for MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN on the button. When the button is clicked, you could create an instance of the Docter class or whatever your game class is.

Comment: As a side note, in Docter, all of your methods should be at the same level as the constructor, not inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i'll sure check it out